# Value of type 'UITextDocumentProxy.Protocol' does not conform to 'UIKeyInput' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code :

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
let title = button.title(for: .normal)
(UITextDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(title!)
```

But Xcode 9.4 (Swift 4) complains that:

> Value of type 'UITextDocumentProxy.Protocol' does not conform to 'UIKeyInput' in coercion

Comment: Perhaps you should be trying to cast some variable you have instead of a specific protocol.

Answer (score 0):

you cast a protocol to another protocol and call a method on it?

you usually want to work with some instance and maybe cast that...

e.g

```
if let myObject = anotherObjectIGot as? UIKeyInput { ... }
```

a protocol is a type of an object. It isnt an object itself. You need one of those :D a real instance